# Buttons in Iphone

Tags: iphone, uibutton

Is it possible to manually assign an image to a button in the iphone sdk. What i wish to do is to assign a plain card background to a button. When a user clicks the button a picker appears the user makes a selection with the picker the buttons image will to the card selected? I have all the cards saved in my resources already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use image in image view then over this image use an custom button and on click this button an IBAction will call suppose
-(IBAction)call
{
  myPicker.hidden=NO;
}
and in viewWillAppear 
myPicker.hidden=YES;

And use picker view delegate methods for your logic for picker view.

Comment: Thanks. What you mean "degate methods"?

Comment: Its a typing mistake because of hurryness.

Answer (score 3):

Try the fiollowing code:

```
btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"any.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"any_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```